# Cross Forest Authentication - RDP - Have to Manually Specify Domain

Tags: rdp, active-directory

We are having an issue when a user in forestB is connecting via RDP to an XP system in forestA. We are in a transitional state where some users have migrated to our new forest (forestB) but still need access to systems in forestA.

The issue is that when they input their new login credentials for forestB in the form of forestB\username into `mstsc` and hit connect, the XP system they're connecting to doesn't recognize the domain (forestB) and gives them an error stating to make sure the username and domain are correct. At this point they're connected, but sitting at the login screen. The login box shows their username as just username without the domain, so it looks like the domain name isn't being passed through to the system they're connecting to. When at the login screen if they change the username to include the domain, forestB\username, it does let them login. The domain for forestB does not show up in the dropdown list. Because they're able to authenticate by manually specifying the domain, I don't see it being an issue with trusts, or is it?

A little info about the environment is below.

- old.example.com - This is the domain where the systems they're connecting to reside (forestA)
- contoso.com - This is where the user accounts have been migrated to (forestB)
- The version of RDP client is 6.1.7600 on both systems
- Network Level Authentication is on
- There is a two-way transitive trust between example.com and contoso.com
- old.example.com is Windows Server 2003 functional level
- example.com is Windows Server 2003 functional level
- contoso.com is Windows Server 2008 R2 functional level

I hope this makes sense. If you need any additional information please let me know.

Comment: When you cerated the Trust what type of authentication did you select? Forest-wide or Selective? Also, to be clear, is this a Forest Trust or a two-way external trust? I'm assuming it's a Forest trust since you mentioned that it's transitive. Is that correct?

Comment: When I get back to work on Monday I will let you know. I will have to look at how it's configured because I can't remember off the top of my head.

Comment: To answer your questions, it's a Forest trust with Forest-wide authentication.

Comment: I heard today from a colleague that we are going to implement shortcut trusts in the meantime to overcome this.

Comment: I know this is old but I just caught that you're logging into these systems via RDP. In that case the users from the trusted domain (B) need to be in the local Remote Desktop Users groups on the computers in the trusting forest (A).

Comment: You cannot use RDP in cross domain if th NLA is on.